# Windows batch file : Search line for keyword and edit using delimiters

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, text-processing

I am writing a batch file to edit a text file of cygwin to enable chroot without manual intervention.

I want to find  the line which contain keyword **SvcCOPSSH** and then edit 
line to replace number between third and forth using deliminator  colon "**:**"

For example find below line

> SvcCOPSSH:unused_by_nt/2000/xp:**1023**:545:U-WINDOWS-AU90FH5\SvcCOPSSH,S-1-5-21-2xxxx5-2xxx9-7xx50-1031:/var/:/bin/false

and edit **1023** to **0**

> SvcCOPSSH:unused_by_nt/2000/xp:**0**:545:U-WINDOWS-AU90FH5\SvcCOPSSH,S-1-5-21-2xxxx5-2xxx9-7xx50-1031:/var/:/bin/false

Thanks for your help

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Andrew i am learning about batch files, I tried few samples which can replace keyword in file, I hope by evening will be customize things as per my need. Yes forum can help me if any body knows about this already !

Comment: @AndrewCooper Nice blog "What have you tried" . Let me try few thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "^SvcCOPSSH" file.txt') do (
echo %%a:%%b:0:%%d:%%e:%%f:%%g >new.txt
)
del file.txt /f /q
ren new.txt file.txt
```

Just replace `file.txt` with your actual text file.